# Create auto-update Gantt chart

Tags: google-sheets, gantt-chart

I'm trying to create a Gantt chart in Google Sheets that will automatically color the cells corresponding to the start date and duration of the task.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 201810**

I've added a scale option and automated Ids in the chart. Please see the article [here](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/10/16/gantt-chart-template-in-google-sheets/).

---

Paste this formula in G4:

```
=ArrayFormula(--(E4:E13<=G3:U3)*--(E4:E13+F4:F13>G3:U3))
```

And then format your data to show like diagramm.

[Example file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1epSbpbxibKCcKqvs7LEB7KWN4KWWMWHBaiZMN0O4MJk/edit?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: This is both ingenious and simple! Thanks a bunch, mate!