# Auto-fill cells based on time range given in other cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've been working on [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11vyPq9j1Q2DXPEn9e04tnAp798Y-4ggmddtE8RnRBkk/edit?usp=sharing) for a little while, and I believe I need help getting pointed in the right direction. I am working on a few spreadsheets to help the business better understand where the labor hours are being spent, and I've combined a few different sheets used at different places I've worked before. I am trying to automate more of the sheet though, so the end result is that all I would need to do is correctly input all of the employees' hours for the week, which would give me all of the information I'm currently doing by hand.

There are 3 categories in use:

- Planner - just ignore this because it works fine and will not affect the problem.
- Schedule, which is 1 sheet where I put all of the start and end times for each of the team members that week. The drop-down menus are a little cumbersome but overall work. The columns marked "Day Shift" and "Night Shift" calculate the number of hours worked during the respective shift for a given person. For my store, there is a pretty cut-and-dry difference between day and night shifts, so all I really need is the number of labor hours for the shift, which I have used a couple if statements to get the information. (most of the columns are currently hidden just for simplisity)
- the Body Charts, which are six different sheets, one for each day of the week that the business is open. At a previous employer (who let me copy the file for my own use), they highlighted a given position for the time frame they wanted that position active. Position one is mostly to get the store running for the day, so it typically only runs from the earliest part of the morning until late morning (say 5:30am to 10 am).

What I want to figure out how to do is take the information from the Schedule sheet and have it automatically fill in cells on the appropriate Body chart. I've currently just been marking the "Start" time with the TM's name and then copying dashes into the subsequent cells for the remainder of their shift (or until I move them to a different position) so I can easily count how many people I have scheduled at any given time. It's inefficient and needs to be redone every week, but it does more or less work in its current form. There's a rough example of the final product on the Saturday BoH sheet.

For the automation then, I'd like to have a given day (like the currently more or less finished Saturday sheet) fill itself in with the data from the Schedule tab, and I am fine with every single cell being the person's name. So script would need to look at the appropriate section on the Schedule sheet (like Saturday start and end times are columns V and W) and fill in the entire range, while leaving empty spaces where there are not any employees. I've attempted to write if functions, but I haven't been able to get *any* of the information to move over without directly telling it where to look and what to put. (Like "look at Schedule!V7 to put person e in cell f8:V8"). Having the filled cells fit inside the highlighted sections would be nice, but I'd prefer to first just have the information be transcribed.

I think I'll need to use an array formula (or formulas) in a script to have it determine what cells need to be filled (and the only part of that I'm familiar with is assign said script to an image to click on). I've looked at a few different websites to try to better understand array formulas (and I like trying to understand codes written and shared on this site), but something about the array formulas does not click with me.

I view this as a learning experience first and foremost, so I would graciously accept just being pointed in the right direction (like alternate ways of thinking about the problem or the formulas). And please let me know if I need to re-write this. This isn't the first time I shared this problem, but I definitely did not explain it well enough previously, so I'd like to be able to better phrase questions too.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This question is unnecessarily long and not a good fit for this site.  Prior to editing it, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and familiarize yourself with the site.  Then, review [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also how to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Peirce, make your spreadsheet "View only" so that users don't (accidentally or otherwise) write over your sample data. The alternative is to create a [link directly to a new copy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/79381/196152).

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks! This was already a copy of the file I actually use, so I didn't think of that.

Comment: I'm loathe to post an answer because it would/could (potentially) limit any chance of another user providing a solution. So, would something such as  ![this image](https://imgur.com/gallery/hjWOQST) suit?

Comment: Two things: 1) the image (in preceding comment) shows every shift finishing at 11:00!! I've fixed that.  2) I suggest that you read [Create auto-update Gantt chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602917/1330560) as well as @MaxMakhrov 's blog post [Gantt Chart Template in Google Sheets](https://sheetswithmaxmakhrov.wordpress.com/2018/10/16/gantt-chart-template-in-google-sheets/). Let me know if you want me to explain how I got my figures, and you may want to take it from there.

Comment: Tedinoz, I would love to see how you made that happen. At the very least, it will be another tool to potentially use in the future. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a visual Gantt-style chart for your daily employee shift roster. You have a sheet ("Schedule") which contains the names of each employee and their start and end time of their daily shift(s).

There are precedents for this style of chart. A very good example is the answer to [Create auto-update Gantt chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36602917/1330560) by @MaxMakhrov. In that example, the data is tracked by day whereas your data is tracked by hour in 15 minute increments. It's worth noting that the number of increments is NOT important - this is because a component of the formula includes the tracking range and this dynamically expands/contracts according to the start/finish time.

---

**Instructions**

**SHEET:Schedule**

- nothing required.

**SHEET:Saturday BOH**

- **ID Columns and Headers**
- Insert 3 new columns to the left of Column B (Allocated Hours); so the first shift column becomes Column F
- Cell B3, enter "ID"
- Cell C3, enter "Start"
- Cell D3, enter "End"
- Cell C4, enter this formula `=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(B4:B34,Schedule!$A$3:$Y$29,22,0),""))`

  - populates the column with the shift "Start Time" based on an employee ID entered in Column B
- Cell D4, enter this formula `=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(B4:B34,Schedule!$A$3:$Y$29,23,0),""))`

  - populates the column with the shift "End Time" based on an employee ID entered in Column B
- Column C and Column D can be hidden once the formulas are entered

---

- **GANTT formula**
- Cell F4, enter this formula `=ArrayFormula(--(C4:C34<=F2:BY2)*--(D4:D34>=F2:BY2))`

  - this will populate the sheet for every shift
  - before conditional formatting, it will display 0 and 1 in shift cells

---

- **Conditional formatting**
- select the range "F4:BY34" (first shift to last shift, first row to last row)

  - Format, Clear Formatting (note: this wiped the cell borders so you may wish to experiment with this)
  - Format, Conditional formatting,

    - "is equal to"
    - 0
    - Fill color = white
    - Text color = white
  - for each employee group colour, select the equivelent range of shift columns and rows (and afterwards, "Add another range" if necessary)
  - Format, Conditional Formatting,

    - "is equal to"
    - 1
    - Fill color = match the employee group colour
    - Text color = match the employee group colour

---

**SAMPLE**

The result should look something like this.

[image]

Comment: `=arrayformula(ifna(vlookup(B4:B34,Schedule!$A$3:$Y$29,{22,23},0),""))` This formula can be entered in cell C4 and will populate both column C and D. (that is, replace the formula in Cell C4 and delete the formula in cell D4)

Comment: The information in Columns C and D is NOT required. Insert this formula in cell F4 `=ArrayFormula(--(ifna(vlookup(B4:B34,Schedule!$A$3:$Y$29,22,0),"")<=D2:BW2)*--(ifna(vlookup(B4:B34,Schedule!$A$3:$Y$29,23,0),"")>=D2:BW2))`. Then delete columns C & D.

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much @Tedinoz! If you could, please confirm whether I'm understanding all this correctly: First, Column B is the ID that the array formula is checking against (I'll experiment to see if I can get that to just copy the IDs from the Schedule?); then the array formula (I just skipped straight to the last one after reading through all of your notes) compares the ID to the Schedule range (noted by the 22 or 23 in this case), and it prints nothing if the value is less than or equal to (or greather than or equal to) the timeframe given in row 2 but places a 1 if the data matches?

Comment: You got it. **BTW#1**: value in Column B is entered manually. **BTW#2**: index=22=Sat start time, index=23=Sat end time. By changing the vlookup index you can use this formula for any day of the week. **BTW#3** `arrayformula` formula in Cell F4 is in two parts, each part returns true or false (1 or 0). Multiplying the two parts returns true (value=1) _ONLY if BOTH are true_ (start time is <= shift time AND end time >= shift time)-that's how the conditional formatting rules rely on values of 0 or 1.

Comment: What does the -- do? I noticed that in the article you linked to as well but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov might help us with an explanation for the use of the decrement operator in this formula. I also wondered what they were for and I looked up the javascript documentation. To be brutally honest, I included them because Max Max Makhrov's formula included them. I have since tried the formula with them, and I can't see any difference. :)